# Access loop variable from within function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops, variables

Not the greatest title i know, alright, consider:

```
for (var i = 0; i < map.length; ++i) {
place_ore(mountain_ore,mountain_allowed_ores) 
}
```

And inside `place_ore()`, I am trying to access `map[i]`;, however when I try to do this, it gives me an undefined error. I think it has something to do with scope, but I can't quite work it out myself, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `i` doesn't exist inside the function..you can always pass `i` in as another variable.

Comment: What's the definition of the function `place_ore`? Does it allow a third parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass it in:

```
for (var i = 0; i < map.length; ++i) {
    place_ore(mountain_ore,mountain_allowed_ores, map[i]) 
}
```

And of course, modify your function signature:

```
function place_ore(mountain_ore,mountain_allowed_ores, mapTile) {
   //..place some ore in mapTile instead of map[i]
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, I didn't think about passing it using place_ore() - well, thank you tonnes!